# Fonts and Sounds in subfolder with Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

I have a project built in Corona SDK that contains a true-type font "BigBimboNC".

When the font is placed into the root directory, the simulator and compiled apps will display correctly. If I place the font into a more organised directory structure (/assets/fonts) then it seems to display on the simulator on WIndows correctly, on the Mac it displays a default font, and whem compiled and tested on an iPad, I see no text at all.

The build.settings contains the following section:

```
iphone =
{
    plist=
    {
        UIStatusBarHidden=true,
        UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = false,
        UIAppFonts = 
                       {
                               "assets/fonts/BigBimboNC.ttf"
                       },
        CFBundleIconFiles = {
            "Icon.png" , 
            "Icon@2x.png" , 
               "Icon-72.png" , 
           },
           UIPrerenderedIcon = true,
    },
},
```

I've seen problems when trying to reference assets with a leading / (fine on the simulator, but fails on the device). This problem is also true for sound files, however images seem fine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource files for everything (e.g. images, sound files, fonts and lua files) should be in a flat directory.

At [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/01/29/app-works-corona-simulator-goes-black-screen-device-simulator#comment-27217) they discussed about some pitfalls that anyone may encounter when using Corona SDK.

The only way is to restructure the whole folder.

Comment: I hope they change this soon. The strange thing is - I can place image file in a nested subdirectory and this works fine (PC & Mac emulators and on iPad / Android phone). Sound also works ok. Just the fonts that won't play nice in a subdirectory. I'll run some more tests but thanks for the link.